Black screen after suspending with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Firstly, I know that this question has been already answered. However, the model of the laptop (specially GPU, which I think is the problem) is really different. I am currently using an HP Victus with a 3050 Nvidia GPU. I am not using any HDMI or any external screen, just the laptop.
The main problem is when trying to "awake" the laptop after suspending it. I will obtain a couple of "screenshots" of the menu for unlocking it, just before turning all into black. Notice that keyboard and mouse do not work/react when trying to use them.
I have tried installing drivers such from 470 to the latest. None of those did work, and I had some problems with the screen (the screen was half-cutted) when using some of those (470, 515...)
For installing the drivers, I have tried two different approaches (using the console and using Software Updates App). When using the console:
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get autoremove

Then I reboot the system.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470

Then reboot again. For instance, driver-470. I have tried the same for other drivers.
When executing nvidia-smi, everything seemed correct (the driver seems to be activated and correctly installed).

I have also tried executing the following command with the previously mentioned drivers installed:
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service

then,
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia

without obtaining any solution.
I've been using the recovery mode and executing the following commands:
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470
sudo reboot

Another thing I have tried, and this is interesting, is to work with the integrated GPU.
sudo prime-select intel

This seems to work perfectly (I can suspend as normal). However, if I execute:
sudo prime-select nvidia

The screen feels very bugged and the suspend does not work again.

Please list the steps, all of them that you used to try out each driver.

@DavidDE I have updated the question with more information. If you need more, do not hesitate to ask it for.

Problem solved. It is important to notice that I'm using the same machine as here
